# Using JQuery to count number of questions unanswered

Tags: jquery, forms

Hi so here is my scenario:

I have a series of divs, (div0,div1,div2) each div, contains a question, like a multiple choice (radio buttons) or, multi-response (checkboxes) or simple text input.

each div has `class='question'`.

I want to try and Identify on clicking a button count how many questions have been unanswered.

I currently can get it to count the number of inputs where `value =''` however the radio buttons etc. all have a value set.

So could anyone throw me some suggestions on how I could go about this?

many thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make your script work with `:input` and `each` along with different options for different types. For input with type text you can use `$(this).val() != ''` and for selects `$("selectclassorid option:selected")` and for checkboxes

```
$('input[name=foo]').is(':checked')
```

or

```
$('input[name=foo]').attr('checked')
```

Using the `:input` selector, you can easily to take the `type` value of `$(this)`.

I hope all of that make sense to you.

Answer (score 0):

1) Initialy you have to get number(length) of div's(questions) as follow

```
var Lenth = $("**div .question**").find("[type='checkbox']").length;
```

2) Using each function get all div's and check current div checkbox was checked or not.

```
$("**div .question**").find("[type='checkbox']").each(function(){
    if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
       //do your error message enable here 
    }
});
```

3) If condition returns `false` you can show error or warning message "This question is Un-Answered".

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Thanks for your answer but the question is 5 years old! It could still be helpful but try to keep an eye on the date ;)